#  compare strings with one having nonreadable chars

Tags: c#

I am having problem regarding comparing two strings. One string has one or more nonreadable characters in it while other other string is same but in readable format.

When I try to use this, I am having trouble

```
if (Alemria=Almería)...
```

I am having such string `Almería` in a table.

How can this be done?

Comment: í is a readable character. You could make a custom string-comparing function to account for these characters, though.

Comment: try 'if(var.StartsWith("Almer"))'

Comment: 1) `==` is the equality operator. 2) Do you really mean `if ("Alemria"=="Almería")`? Because that is comparing two strings. As written, it would be comparing two variables.

Comment: Define unreadable please. You say the strings are the same but one is unreadable and the other isn't so they really are not the same. are you only trying to compare the "readable" portion of each string?

Comment: @unholysampler: Serious? It's pretty clear what the question is...

Comment: The question is how to treat "i" and "í" (as well as other accented characters) as the same character when doing a string compare.

Answer (score 2):

Use an overload of [`string.Equals`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e1f0cx84.aspx) that takes a [`StringComparison`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.stringcomparison.aspx) enum - use one of the `CurrentCulture` enum members.

You will need to set the current culture to a culture that can sort by these characters.

Comment: nice idea but `Console.WriteLine("Alemria".Equals("Almería",StringComparison.CurrentCulture));` produces False.

Comment: @Cos - it depends on the current culture, though I am not sure that `i` == `í` in _any_ culture.

Comment: can we perform this comparison in sql server? if yes then how?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how strict you want to be, you might try this. If you know the characters in question are only from spanish the alphabet you could strip those out of the seed values (maybe use RegEx) and modify your comparison logic to do the same with target records. For example, remove all 'ñ' and 'n' from both side and maybe add a length comparison to increase reliability. Of course do this with all the special characters, not just 'ñ'.

Answer (score 0):

See if [this article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/90338/Convert-Accented-Characters-to-Simple-Characters.aspx) will help you, you could replace all accented characters in the word and then do your comparison.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose `CompareOptions.IgnoreNonSpace` is that you are looking for. Compare will ignore accents, diacritics, and vowel marks.

```
        string str1 = "mun";
        string str2 = "mün";
        int result1 = string.Compare(str1, str2, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, CompareOptions.IgnoreNonSpace);
        int result2 = string.Compare(str1, str2, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, CompareOptions.IgnoreNonSpace);
```

But Alemria will differ from Almería anyway. Seems like it's considered totally another symbol.

Answer (score -2):

Try

```
    if(var.StartsWith("Almer"))//repalce var with your string var
    MessageBox.Show("String matched");//do watever you want to do here
```

Comment: So it matches "Almersupercalifragilisticexpialidocious" too?

Comment: dear friends, actually i want to compare two values of statesName. one is i am getting from excel file i.e (Almeria) and from db end i am getting (Almería).... So when i want to fetch data from db on basis of 'Almeria', it returns nothing....Important thing is that we don't know either given words has special chars in db or not.. i simply using values from excel file without knowing whats its representation in database....How can i do it... Please help... It took my much time... Thnaks